# Why PID of debugged process exists only in debugger?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, pid

I am having a C program that tells its PID to other C program so they can communicate. I am using `getpid()` function on Linux and everything works fine until I try to debug one of the programs with VS Code. The pid function returns in this case 'non-existing' PID. If I look to `ps uax` it is not there. However, if I do `-exec info inferior`, inside the debug console, it displays the same PID, which I could not find. Is there some way how to properly debug files calling `getpid()` or `getppid()` functions?

Comment: Curious, what do you mean by "The pid function returns in this case non-existing PID". getpid always returns a PID, it cannot fail. 

PIDs exist in namespaces which can be inherited from parent processes. If the debugger is changing the namespace of your process, then the PID won't be usable from other processes in the global namespace.

Comment: If I use plain gdb or even Eclipse (which uses gdb) I get a proper PID of debugged process (around 4000). Both programs can connect and debugging is without any problems. I have tried to use VS Code and its debugger (which also uses gdb). The PID of process during debugging with this tool is nonsence (<1000) and therefore, programs can not connect properly.